# responsive image layout

Tags: javascript, jquery

So I have multiple div's with the same class and inside them images that can be from 1 to 4 depending on the div, I do not know in advance how many images because they come from the database.
How can I give the images different classes depending on how many there are in the div. MY html

```
<section class="feed-section">
    <article class="feed-article">
        <div class="question-options">
            <img src="http://placehold.it/600x400">
        </div>
    </article>
    <article class="feed-article">
        <div class="question-options">
            <img src="http://placehold.it/600x400">
            <img src="http://placehold.it/600x400">
            <img src="http://placehold.it/600x400">
            <img src="http://placehold.it/600x400">
        </div>
    </article>
    <article class="feed-article">
        <div class="question-options">
            <img src="http://placehold.it/600x400">
            <img src="http://placehold.it/600x400">
            <img src="http://placehold.it/600x400">
        </div>
    </article>
</section>
```

my js

```
function imagesWidth() {
    var imagesConatiner = $('.question-options').each(function (index) {
        var images = $(this).children('img').length;
        switch (images) {
        case 1:
            $('.question-options img').addClass('one')
            break;
        case 2:
            $('.question-options img').addClass('two')
            break;
        case 3:
            $('.question-options img').addClass('three')
            break;
        case 4:
            $('.question-options img').addClass('four')
            break;
        default:
            console.log(images)
        }
    })
};
imagesWidth()
```

The problem now is that it ads multiple classes for example to all the images it adds one for three

I want to do them with css like

```
img.one {
    width:100%
}
img.two {
    width:50%
}
```

And so on...

Comment: I still get 2 or 3 classes per image , i want a clas per div/image

Answer (score 2, accepted):

the problem is the context to what you are adding the class, since you are getting all the `question-options` container. try this:

```
function imagesWidth() {
    var imagesConatiner = $('.question-options').each(function (index) {
        var images = $(this).children('img').length;
        var self = $(this);

        switch (images) {
            case 1:
                self.children('img').addClass('one')
                break;
            case 2:
                self.children('img').addClass('two')
                break;
            case 3:
                self.children('img').addClass('three')
                break;
            case 4:
                self.children('img').addClass('four')
                break;
            default:
                console.log(images)
        }
    })
};
imagesWidth()
```

here is an example [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/ftg2ba7w/)

Answer (score 1):

Your code should be this:

```
function imagesWidth() {
    var imagesConatiner = $('.question-options').each(function (index) {
        var images = $(this).children('img').length;
        switch (images) {
        case 1:
            $(this).find('img').addClass('one')
            break;
        case 2:
            $(this).find('img').addClass('two')
            break;
        case 3:
            $(this).find('img').addClass('three')
            break;
        case 4:
            $(this).find('img').addClass('four')
            break;
        default:
            console.log(images)
        }
    })
};
imagesWidth()
```

You were not referencing the parent div as 'this' so was adding classes to all '.question-options' child 'img' tags.

Answer (score 0):

The problem with your code is that you're using a general selector to add class on images. `$('.question-options img')` will select all the images inside the element having class `question-options`. You can use `find`, `children` with the current context(`$(this)`) or context selector to select the images which are inside the current element inside the `each`.

```
$('img', this).addClass('someclass');
```

This will add the class to all the `img` elements which are inside the current element. i.e. `.question-options` on which iterating.

Your problem will be solved by using any of the above approach.

If you're looking for an *flexible* and *optimized* solution,

1. You can use an array with index as number of images and value as the class
2. Add the class at the index to all the images

```js
// Create array for the classes, index will be treated as number of images and value is the class to add
// Modify the array according to the maximum number of elements
var classes = ['', 'one', 'two', 'three', 'four'];

function imagesWidth() {
  var imagesConatiner = $('.question-options').each(function(index) {

    // Get the value from the array at the index i.e. no. of images and add it as class to all the images inside this container
    $('img', this).addClass(classes[$(this).children('img').length]);
  })
};
imagesWidth();
```

```css
img.one {
  width: 100%
}
img.two {
  width: 50%
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.10.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<section class="feed-section">
  <article class="feed-article">
    <div class="question-options">
      <img src="http://placehold.it/600x400">
    </div>
  </article>
  <article class="feed-article">
    <div class="question-options">
      <img src="http://placehold.it/600x400">
      <img src="http://placehold.it/600x400">
      <img src="http://placehold.it/600x400">
      <img src="http://placehold.it/600x400">
    </div>
  </article>
  <article class="feed-article">
    <div class="question-options">
      <img src="http://placehold.it/600x400">
      <img src="http://placehold.it/600x400">
      <img src="http://placehold.it/600x400">
    </div>
  </article>
</section>
```

Answer (score 0):

Do you have a specific reason to add specific classes per image? You could achieve the same effect (making sure the images are evenly distributed accross a set width) using pure css flexbox and no javascript.

```
.question-options {
    display: flex;
    width: 500px;
    flex-direction: row;
    padding: 10px;
    background-color: blue;
}
.question-options div {
    flex: 1 1 auto;
}
.question-options img {
    width: 100%;
}
```

You will however need to wrap your images in a div to make it work:

```
<section class="feed-section">
  <article class="feed-article">
    <div class="question-options">
        <div><img src="http://placehold.it/600x400"></div>
    </div>
  </article>
  <article class="feed-article">
    <div class="question-options">
        <div><img src="http://placehold.it/600x400"></div>
        <div><img src="http://placehold.it/600x400"></div>
        <div><img src="http://placehold.it/600x400"></div>
        <div><img src="http://placehold.it/600x400"></div>
    </div>
  </article>
  <article class="feed-article">
    <div class="question-options">
        <div><img src="http://placehold.it/600x400"></div>
        <div><img src="http://placehold.it/600x400"></div>
        <div><img src="http://placehold.it/600x400"></div>
    </div>
  </article>
</section>
```

Fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/grxp0gw1/

NB: Flexbox does not (yet) play nice with images. Thanks to [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/30792956/5358807) and [this fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/techsin/xLc2Le0k/6/) I was able to make it work.

Comment: (updated answer with links to more help on making this work with css)

Comment: This is not what OP wants, OP want if there are multiple images they should be minimised to show all the images in a container

Comment: A Flexbox like solution could do exactly what OP wants. It can make sure that if you have x components (images) they are equally wide and fit exactly in container. Isn't that what OP wants to achieve?

Comment: Yes, but the demo you've added doesn't shows something what OP wants, can you please update the demo