# Firefox bug: image does not scale down?

Tags: html, css, firefox, flexbox

Is this a bug in firefox?

CSS,

```
html, body {
    height: 100%;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0 0;
    /*border: 4px solid black;*/
}

.container-fluid {
    height: 100%;
    width: 100%;
    display: table;
    padding-right: 0;
    padding-left: 0;
    /*border: 4px solid blue;*/
}

.row-fluid {
    height: 100%;
    width: 100%;
    display: table-cell;
    vertical-align: middle;
    background-color:#990000;
    /*border: 4px solid red;*/
}

.img-container {
    height: 100vh;
    width: 100%;
    display: flex;
    align-items: center;
}

.img-container img{
    max-width:100%;
    max-height:100%;
    margin-left: auto;
    margin-right: auto;
}
```

HTML,

```
  <div class="container-fluid">
    <div class="row-fluid">
        <div class="img-container">
            <!-- <img src="http://placehold.it/400x450"> -->
            <img src="http://placehold.it/2000x450">
            <!-- <img src="http://placehold.it/400x480"> -->
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Chrome,

[image]

The large image will be scaled down to fit the screen width which is what I want.

Firefox,

[image]

The image is **not** scaled down to fit the screen.

Any ideas how I can fix this?

**EDIT:**

```
@-moz-document url-prefix() {
    .img-container img {
        width: 100%;
        max-width: -moz-max-content;
    }
}
```

[image]

Comment: How many images you're going to have in the "img-container"?

Comment: @Pangloss one image per "img-container".

Comment: eventually I will have a list of "img-container" for making a bootstrap carousal.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you are using CSS table for the layout already, I'm suggesting this approach without flexbox. It works nicely on Chrome and Firefox according to my tests. I added a `div` around the `img`.

**[jsFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/a8zLrcr7/1/)**

```css
body { margin:0; }

.img-container {
  display: table;
  table-layout: fixed; /*required for responsive width in Firefox*/
  width: 100%; /*required for fixed table layout*/
}
.img-container .image {
  display: table-cell;
  text-align: center;
  vertical-align: middle;
  height: 100vh; /*required for responsive height*/
}
.img-container .image img {
  max-width: 100%;
  max-height: 100%;
  vertical-align: middle; /*remove whitespace*/
}
```

```html
<div class="img-container">
  <div class="image">
    <img src="http://placehold.it/400x300">
    <!-- <img src="http://placehold.it/2000x450"> -->
    <!-- <img src="http://placehold.it/400x480"> -->
  </div>
</div>
```

Alternatively, you can use pseudo element `:before` or `:after` + inline block for vertical alignment. No markup change is required.

**[jsFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/jhaakwpq/)**

```css
body { margin:0; }

.img-container {
  width: 100vw; /*required for responsive width in Firefox*/
  height: 100vh;
  text-align: center;
  font-size: 0; /*remove whitespace*/
}
.img-container:after {
  content: "";
  display: inline-block;
  height: 100%;
  vertical-align: middle;
}
.img-container img {
  max-width: 100%;
  max-height: 100%;
  vertical-align: middle;
}
```

```html
<div class="img-container">
  <img src="http://placehold.it/400x300">
  <!-- <img src="http://placehold.it/2000x450"> -->
  <!-- <img src="http://placehold.it/400x480"> -->
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

Yes there is problem in firefox. It will not maintaining aspect ratio. To make it working just add `width: 100%;` to image will solve issue.

```
.img-container img {
    margin-left: auto;
    margin-right: auto;
    max-height: 100%;
    max-width: 100%;
    width: 100%;
}
```

**[Working Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/44fgj2wq/1/)**

Check same type of issue [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30788131/css3-flexbox-maintain-image-aspect-ratio).

**Edit:**

To solve issue for all size image use `max-width: -moz-max-content;`

```
@-moz-document url-prefix() {

    .img-container img { width: 100%; max-width: -moz-max-content; }
}
```

**[Updated Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/44fgj2wq/6/)**

Comment: Thanks but it breaks `<img src="http://placehold.it/400x450">`. I don't want it to scale when the image is small...

Comment: thanks for the edit. still have a little bug with the small images. Please see my edit above.

Comment: @teelou If you do not want to scale image then remove `width:100%` for mozilla

Comment: it is the height having the problem now.

Answer (score 1):

Based on a bug report (see below), this is a known issue with Firefox. (Although IE11 also fails to scale the image as desired).

This seems to solve the problem in Firefox:

Instead of:

```
.img-container img {
    max-width: 100%;
    max-height: 100%;
    margin-left: auto;
    margin-right: auto;
}
```

Try this:

```
.img-container img {
    width: 100%;           /* adjusted */
    height: auto;          /* adjusted */
    margin-left: auto;
    margin-right: auto;
}
```

[**DEMO**](https://jsfiddle.net/mL557rrz/1/)

Another possible solution involves adding `table-layout: fixed` to the main container (`.container-fluid`). This method is detailed in this bug report:

- [**Bug 975632 - `max-width: 100%;` doesn't work inside tables or `display: table`**](https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/show_bug.cgi?id=975632)

Comment: Thanks but it breaks `<img src="http://placehold.it/400x450">`. I don't want it to scale when the image is small...