# How to use flexbox with img's

Tags: html, css, image, flexbox

I am trying to produce a vertical stack of two images that scale with different viewport sizes. I wish that all images preserve their aspect ratio and use flexbox (not an absolute requirement but ideal).

Right now my HTML is like this

```
 <div class="fullwidth">
   <div class="verticalimages">
     <img src="http://placehold.it/500x600">
     <img src="http://placehold.it/500x600">
   </div>
 </div>
```

with CSS

```
.fullwidth{
    width:100%;
}

.verticalimages{
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: column;
    width: 33.3%;
    height: calc(33.3% * 600 / 500);
}
```

The width of the images scale accordingly but not the height. What am I doing wrong?

I have the code here:

http://codepen.io/anon/pen/Rrmyyd

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using `flex` for images is, at least for now, a bad idea, as it has many [flaws and bugs](https://stackoverflow.com/a/30792956/2827823), so if you take that part out, you'll get something like this, that might be a solution for you.

If you still need `flex`, the recommended way is to [wrap each `img`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/30792956/2827823) using a `div`.

```css
.fullwidth {
  width: 100%;
}

.verticalimages {
}

.verticalimages img {
    display: block;
    width: 33.3%;
    height: auto;
}
```

```html
<div class="fullwidth">
  <div class="verticalimages">
    <img src="http://placehold.it/500x600">
    <img src="http://placehold.it/500x600">
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: What about with flexbox? Is it possible to do it with display flex on verticalimages?

Comment: @NunoCalaim Updated my answer with an explanation/linked resource.