# How to fit an image vertically in a flex container with direction: column

Tags: html, css, flexbox

I'm trying to fit an image vertically in a flex container which has a specific height.

The `flex-direction` is `column`, and the image is contained in a `flex-item` with `flex-basis: 100%`.

In addition, the image's `max-height` is `100%`.

As you can see in the example, the image does not fit into the red container.

```css
#container {
    background-color: red;
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: column;
    flex-wrap: wrap;
    height: 200px;
    width: 320px;
    justify-content: space-between;
}

#container > * {
  padding: 5px;
}

#img {
  flex: 0 1 100%;
  /* height: 100%; */
}
img {
  max-height: 100%;
  max-width: 100%;
}
```

```html
<div id="container">
    <div id="img">
        <img src="https://placeholdit.imgix.net/~text?txtsize=33&txt=img&w=340&h=500">
    </div>
    <div>
      Something else
    </div>
</div>
```

Shouldn't the image shrink to fit vertically into the flex container, according to the specification?

The workaround I found is to set the `height` of `#img` to `100%`, but I have the sensation that it's not the way it should be done.

As an additional note, if I set `flex-direction: row` to the container, it fits the image horizontally (which is the behaviour I would expect).

Comment: give the image max-width: 100% and height: auto i think that can make it

Comment: @DanyCode Tried it with no effect

Comment: Related? - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30788131/css3-flexbox-maintain-image-aspect-ratio

Comment: how's this? https://jsfiddle.net/6zm20zv4/1/  I think this is the same sort of issue like when you are trying to set a height to 100% of something where the parent doesn't have a height set

Comment: @Paulie_D I think it isn't, as I already wrapped the `img` with a `div` to prevent it to be a direct child of the flex container.

Comment: @pete, but I already set a height for the flex container. Also, this solution breaks the image aspect ratio

Comment: @pau.moreno but if you don't set the height of the immediate parent element of the image, it won't know what to be a max-height of - it's just the way css works: https://jsfiddle.net/6zm20zv4/6

Answer (score 4, accepted):

*You wrote:*

> The workaround I found is to set the height of `#img` to 100%, but I have the sensation that it's not the way it should be done.

Actually, it *is* the way it should be done. The predominant implementation of the spec requires that the `height` property be applied to the parent when using percentage heights on the child. (Although this is slowly evolving. See my second reference below.)

References:

- [Working with the CSS `height` property and percentage values](https://stackoverflow.com/a/31728799/3597276)
- [Heights rendering differently in Chrome and Firefox](https://stackoverflow.com/a/35537510/3597276) (includes alternative solutions)
- [CSS `height` property definition](https://www.w3.org/TR/CSS21/visudet.html#propdef-height) (W3C)

Comment: Wow, you've done quite a lot of research about this!

Answer (score 1):

For some reason, I couldn't get the `<img>` to behave (probably because it's a [replaced element](http://thenewcode.com/461/What-The-Heck-Is-A-Replaced-Element)). So I removed it, and used the `.img` div with an image as background.

**Relevant Changes**

```
.container {
...
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
}

.img {
  flex: 1 0 auto;
  background: url(https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/en/2/24/Lenna.png) no-repeat;
  background-size: contain;
  background-position: center;
  width: 100%;
}
```

**SNIPPET**

```css
.container {
  background-color: red;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
  height: 200px;
  width: 320px;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
}
.container > * {
  padding: 5px;
}
.somethingElse {
  outline: 1px dashed yellow;
  background: rgba(128,0,255,.3);
  color: white;
}
.img {
  flex: 1 0 auto;
  background: url(https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/en/2/24/Lenna.png) no-repeat;
  background-size: contain;
  background-position: center;
  width: 100%;
}
```

```html
<figure class="container">
  <div class="img">

  </div>

  <figcaption class="somethingElse">
    True Dimentions: 512 x 512 px 
  </figcaption>
</figure>
```

Answer (score -1):

try this css. its works fine.

```
#container {
    background-color: red;
    /*display: flex;*/
    flex-direction: column;
    flex-wrap: wrap;
    height: 200px;
    width: 320px;
    justify-content: space-between;
}

#img {
  height: 85%;
  width: 100%;
}
```