# image is not resizing in a flexbox layout

Tags: html, css, flexbox, responsive-images

I tried to follow the advice in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/30792956/338638), and as shown in this [CodePen](https://codepen.io/dudleystorey/pen/Kgofa?editors=1100), but the image that needs to flex is still keeping its original dimensions unless the screen is so narrow it is alone on the row.

There is another set of divs in the real page in a similar situation - it would help the page work across a much larger range of widths if the side divs would shrink.

The div it is wrapped in has `flex: auto;` on it and `img {width: 90%; height: auto;}` for any image in it, the parent of that div has `style="flex: 0 1 250px;"` on it.

Here is a [CodePen](http://codepen.io/kimholder/pen/ZLeNPM?editors=1100) of it.

I guess there is a simple mistake, if not I suppose I'll make the image the background of the div it is currently in, and set `background-size: 100% auto;` on it.

```css
section {
  padding: 15px;
  display: flex;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
  margin-top: 3vw;
  margin-left: 6vw;
}
.outerDiv {
  background-color: rgba(50, 50, 0, 0.5);
}
.innerDiv {
  background-color: rgba(10, 10, 10, 0.6);
  display: flex;
  flex-flow: column nowrap;
  align-items: flex-end;
  margin: 15px;
}
.innerDiv p {
  padding: 6px 18px 0 15px;
}
.imgResize {
  flex: auto;
  align-self: center;
  padding: 15px;
}
.imgResize img {
  width: 90%;
  height: auto;
}
```

```html
<section>

  <div class="outerDiv">
    <div class="innerDiv" style="flex: 0 1 250px;">
      <h2>The Rocket Equation</h2>
      <p>Mass ratio:</p>
      <div class="imgResize">
        <a href="rotovator.html">
          <img src="http://www.moonwards.com/img/animatedRotovatorLink.png">
        </a>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>

  <div class="outerDiv">
    <div class="innerDiv">
      <h2>Suborbital Hop</h2>
      <img src="http://www.moonwards.com/img/mapmini.jpg" width="512" height="256">
      <canvas id="subOrbitalCanvas" width="512" height="256"></canvas>
    </div>
  </div>

</section>
```

Comment: It's unclear what the problem is exactly. The image in `.imgResize > a > img` is behaving responsively because of the relative 90% width attribute, which makes it adapt with the parent. What do you mean exactly by "the image that needs to flex is still keeping its original dimensions"? It resizes when the window gets small.

Comment: @MichaelCoker It resizes only after the second outerDiv has wrapped. I'd like it to shrink to give it room, and grow when it has extra room.

Comment: why not just remove `flex-wrap: wrap;` from `section` so the 2nd outerDiv doesn't wrap?

Comment: @MichaelCoker There are other divs that are similar on the real page, it would work better over a lot of widths if they would shrink.

Answer (score 64):

An initial setting on flex items is `min-width: auto`. This means that a flex item, by default, cannot shrink below the size of its content.

In this case, the `section` element is the primary flex container.

The flex items are `.outerDiv`.

Because these flex items contain images, they cannot shrink below the image's size. To overcome this, override the default with `min-width: 0`.

[**revised codepen**](http://codepen.io/anon/pen/apJeYL?editors=1100)

Okay, so now the item can shrink past the content, but the image is still inflexible.

You can fix that with:

```
img { width: 100%; height: auto; }
```

[**revised codepen**](http://codepen.io/anon/pen/Qdperb?editors=1100)

Here's more information: *[Why doesn't flex item shrink past content size?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/36247140/3597276)*

Comment: I'm going to have to read that over more carefully in the morning. The image i want to shrink did have that, as 90% and auto, in the class called .imgResize. I need the other one to keep its size, so i did it that way. The behaviour in the revised codepen still has the behavior that is troublesome - the first div set doesn't shrink until after the second has wrapped.

Comment: It wasn't clear exactly what you want, but hopefully the concept of flex item minimum sizing and the link reference lead you to a resolution. Otherwise, feel free to post more details here.

Comment: I ended up making the image smaller to sidestep the issue. It's too much to fiddle with right now. The material here was helpful though.

Comment: For `flex-direction: column`, I had to use `min-height: auto`. Thank you so much, this saved me :)

Comment: As for @Prid , I added a `min-h-0` with tailwindcss to fix an image stretching wider than the parent container. Thank you for this answer.

Comment: Thanks, this helped me solve my problem. The <img> in my flex layout wouldn't shrink, but setting `min-width` to zero allowed it to get smaller.