# Bootstrap 4 - <img> w-100 is not fitting parent flex div ... if <img> is smaller than parent div?

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, bootstrap-4

I'm breaking my head about this, and cannot seem to solve it.

When I'm adding an image of 100px width to a desktop site, and apply the class `w-100` to it, it should stretch to the width of the parent div (column in this case), right? That's how it works when you do this:

```
<div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-8">
        <img src="image-w100px.jpg" class="img-fluid w-100">
    </div>
    <div class="col-md-4">
    </div>
</div>
```

However if I try to do the same inside a flex div (to center/middle align the picture next to a large amount of text, it won't work

```
<div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-8 flex">
        <div class="align-self-center">
            <img src="image-w100px.jpg" class="img-fluid w-100">
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="col-md-4">
        Large amount of text (picture on the left should vertically align.
    </div>
</div>
```

I have tried every combination (img-fluid alone, w-100 alone, combination of img-fluid and w-100, removing classes and adding style="width: 100% !important"), but none of the possibilities make my img expand further than it's original size, it'll compress/resize to a lower size, but not expand.

Why is this not working?

Comment: No, just bootstrap - nothing else. And I can reproduce it using a boilerplate BS4 template. So it's not other code that's interfering.

Comment: Unable to reproduce

Comment: I updated my question, as I didn't notice I had applied a flex class to the parent div.

Comment: Flex is the issue: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41774646/image-is-not-resizing-in-a-flexbox-layout

Answer (score 0):

After testing some more, I found a solution. Adding `w-100` to the `align-self-center` class, it now works:

```
<div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-8 flex">
        <div class="align-self-center w-100">
            <img src="image-w100px.jpg" class="img-fluid w-100">
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="col-md-4">
        Large amount of text (picture on the left should vertically align.
    </div>
</div>
```