# How to correctly resize an svg?

Tags: html, css, svg

I'm trying to display the following `svg`s next to another but it looks like they don't resize proportionally once the container becomes narrow. I tried using `preserveAspectRatio` on the `symbol` but that seems to simply align the svg within the container.

```css
.stars {
    display: flex;
    justify-content: space-between;
    background: blue;
}

.star {
    width: 18%;
}
```

```html
<svg style="display:none;">
    <symbol id="star" viewBox="0 0 992.13 945.383">
        <path fill="#F89838" d="M495.844.165c7.74-.957 14.046 2.317 18.812 7.944 3.975 4.693 7.522 9.955 10.256 15.463 43.75 88.155 87.396 176.36 130.81 264.68 2.617 5.322 5.912 7.364 11.415 8.154 69.738 10.02 139.453 20.197 209.173 30.347 28.152 4.098 56.33 8.032 84.425 12.49 6.248.99 12.58 3.135 18.203 6.042 12.05 6.228 16.57 18.336 10.513 30.486-3.873 7.77-9.527 15.062-15.745 21.184-49.78 49.012-99.885 97.695-149.893 146.476-19.908 19.42-39.77 38.884-59.8 58.18-2.86 2.756-3.798 5.24-3.097 9.263C771.55 671.95 781.99 733.06 792.49 794.16c6.286 36.574 12.824 73.106 18.692 109.745 1.132 7.07.674 14.763-.785 21.81-3.15 15.218-14.692 22.285-29.89 18.79-5.766-1.326-11.482-3.572-16.736-6.324C676.586 892.5 589.455 846.71 502.41 800.76c-4.675-2.468-8.086-2.47-12.765 0-85.87 45.32-171.84 90.455-257.81 135.58-4.512 2.368-9.103 4.72-13.896 6.392-23.697 8.265-41.205-5.358-38.025-30.316 2.78-21.805 6.855-43.45 10.568-65.13 12.603-73.59 24.73-147.27 38.407-220.662 2.98-15.997-.78-25.543-12.282-36.525C150.31 526.8 84.845 462.633 19.29 398.567c-5.81-5.677-11.155-12.242-15.147-19.283-8.553-15.088-3.645-30.02 12.75-35.668 12.667-4.364 26.293-6.275 39.642-8.27 60.228-8.997 120.51-17.648 180.774-26.4 29.032-4.217 58.054-8.52 87.127-12.45 5.823-.787 9.258-2.85 11.983-8.395 43.206-87.927 86.623-175.75 130.195-263.498 3.117-6.278 7.34-12.17 11.898-17.52 4.298-5.05 10.267-7.744 17.33-6.917z"/>
    </symbol>
</svg>

<div class="stars">
    <svg class="star"><use xlink:href="#star"></use> </svg>
    <svg class="star"><use xlink:href="#star"></use> </svg>
    <svg class="star"><use xlink:href="#star"></use> </svg>
    <svg class="star"><use xlink:href="#star"></use> </svg>
    <svg class="star"><use xlink:href="#star"></use> </svg>
</div>
```

Comment: I think you should put your viewBox bounds onto the individual SVG elements containing `use` elements

Comment: Actually this only works when I remove `display: flex`, sorry

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As I already wrote in the comment (and to expand a bit), `viewBox` must be put onto the individual `svg` elements containing the `use` elements eg.

```
<div class="stars">
  <svg class="star" viewBox="0 0 992.13 945.383">
    <use xlink:href="#star"></use>
  </svg>
  <svg class="star" viewBox="0 0 992.13 945.383">
    <use xlink:href="#star"></use>
  </svg>
  ...
</div>
```

Edit: for flexbox, try putting a `div` around `svg` as explained [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30788131/css3-flexbox-maintain-image-aspect-ratio)

Comment: Looks like this does the job but only if I remove `display: flex` from the parent container.

Answer (score 0):

Generally speaking, I find that you have to set svg's width manually in JavaScript.

```
function resizeSvgs() {
    var starsWidth = $(window).innerWidth * .18;//get the percentage from the width
    $(".stars").css({width:starsWidth});
}

resizeSvgs();

$(window).resize(resizeSvgs);
```

I used jQuery.  I would highly recommend using it. It's quite standard and will save you hours of time.