# How can I fit images with varying sizes in a flex row?

Tags: css, flexbox

My understanding of flex is that this;

```
<div class="flex-container">
   <img src="image-1">
   <img src="image-2">
   ...
   <img src ="image-n">
</div>

<style>
   .flex-container {
     display: flex;
     justify-content: space-between;
   }
   .flex-container img {
     flex-shrink: 1;
   }
</style>
```

with random number of random sized images should produce a block of images of width 100% of its parent with the images reduced in size proportionally to fit. I don't want to wrap the items.

The result of the above is either an overflow of the container or distorted images with varying results depending on setting `max-` or `min-height` styles on parent or children.

My understanding is obviously wrong. But why?

I have added the snippet below, in Chrome the images fit the box but are distorted, in Firefox they spill out of the box.

Comment: `.flex-container` is not closed, is it an error or in your code as well ?

Comment: It should be close as duplicate [Maintain image aspect ratio when changing height](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30788131/maintain-image-aspect-ratio-when-changing-height)

Comment: A flex container will just set all children next to each other, does not matter the width you are setting to it, the content will overflow. this is its behave. So I guess there is no solution to your problem as it is seeking for documentation

Answer (score 1):

Setting the images to `display: block` is not sufficient. They need to be enclosed.

Thanks to [Adriano](https://stackoverflow.com/users/4603295/adriano) for the comment suggestion.

```
<div class="flex-container">
   <div>
     <img src="image-1">
   </div>
   <div>
   <img src="image-2">
   </div>
   ...
   <div>
    <img src ="image-n">
   </div> 
</div>

<style>
   .flex-container {
     display: flex;
     justify-content: space-between;
   }
   .flex-container div {
     flex-shrink: 1;
   }
   .flex-container div img {
     width: 100%;
     height: auto;
   }
</style>
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want your image to keep ratio, add `align-items: flex-start;` to your container.

*"The default for the css "align-items" property is "stretch" which is what is causing your images to be stretched to its full original height. Setting the css "align-items" property to "flex-start" fixes your issue."*

Or you set each image into a container (with `display:block;`).

if you want your image to break and go to the next line just add `flex-wrap:wrap;` to your container.

```css
.flex-container {
   display: flex;
   justify-content: space-between;
   /* ADDED */
   align-items: flex-start;
   /*flex-wrap:wrap;*/
}
.flex-container img {
   flex-shrink: 1;
}
```

```html
<div class="flex-container">
   <img src="https://dummyimage.com/600x400/000/fff">
   <img src="https://dummyimage.com/200x600/e31da8/000">
   ...
   <img src ="https://dummyimage.com/60x40/000/fff">
</div>
```

Comment: I still see horizontal scrollbars

Comment: @SalmanA Just `flex-wrap: wrap;` to your container, this is just the normal how of flex behave. and it will go to the next "row"

Comment: if image is larger than body then you can always set a `max-width: 100vw` on it or adjust with media query.

Comment: I don't want them to wrap, that seems to be one of the issues, `align-items: flex-start` has no effect. I will have to mock this up.