# Flexbox maintain aspect ratio for different sized images

Tags: html, css, flexbox

After sorting through dozens of Flexbox questions on this website with no luck, I figure it's time to just ask.

I want a row of images where the row stretches the entire width of the window, each image is the same height, and all images maintain their original aspect ratios. As an example, I have:

```css
ul {
  width: 100%;
  list-style-type: none;
  padding: 0;
  display: flex;
  align-items: stretch;
}

li {
  flex-grow: 1;
  flex-shrink: 1;
  flex-basis: 0;
}

img {
  max-height: 100%;
  max-width: 100%;
  object-fit: contain;
}
```

```html
<ul>
  <li>
    <img src="https://dummyimage.com/1920x1080"/>
  </li>
  <li>
    <img src="https://dummyimage.com/1400x1000"/>
  </li>
  <li>
    <img src="https://dummyimage.com/500"/>
  </li>
</ul>
```

The question [Maintain image aspect ratio when changing height](https://stackoverflow.com/q/30788131/3721066) is very similar, but the problem with those answers is that all the images are the same aspect ratio.

Comment: if the ratio for each image is known, you can do it. For random aspect ratio, it would be difficult (if not impossible)

Comment: I could see how arbitrarily sized images could make this a pain. The ratio of each image is known, and the Flexbox does not wrap.

Comment: I’m not clear why flex is involved. If you know the total width is 100vw then the height is 100vw divided by the sum of the aspect ratios, give or take any gaps required. Have I misunderstood the problem?

Comment: here is an example for **landscape** img of different size using js to do the calculation  https://codepen.io/gc-nomade/pen/vYdwZNm  (flex is here only involved to draw a row from li not in sizing img ) . You may inspire yourself from that codepen

Comment: @G-Cyrillus consider adding it as an answer (I reopened the question since the duplicate is irrelevant)

Comment: @TemaniAfif i answered and removed it cause your answer via js worked fine ;)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ended up combing [@Temani Afif](https://stackoverflow.com/users/8620333/temani-afif)'s and [@G-Cyrillus](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2442099/g-cyrillus)' approaches to get:

```js
let smoothImg = function () {
    const images = document.querySelectorAll("ul li img");
    for (image of images) {
        image.parentElement.style.flexGrow = image.offsetWidth/image.offsetHeight;
    }
};

window.onload = smoothImg;
window.onresize = smoothImg;
```

```css
ul {
  list-style-type: none;
  padding: 0;
  display: flex;
}

li {
  flex-grow: 1;
  flex-basis: 0;
}

img {
  max-width: 100%;
}
```

```html
<ul>
    <li>
        <img src="https://dummyimage.com/1920x1080" />
    </li>
    <li>
        <img src="https://dummyimage.com/1400x1000" />
    </li>
    <li>
        <img src="https://dummyimage.com/200x150" />
    </li>
    <li>
        <img src="https://dummyimage.com/300" />
    </li>
</ul>
```

However, I realized that what I am ultimately attempting is complicated and that I was better off just using a library: https://github.com/naturalatlas/image-layout

Answer (score 2):

If the ratio is know do it like below. Note the use of a variable where you define the ratio of each image

```css
ul {
  list-style-type: none;
  padding: 0;
  display: flex;
}

li {
  flex-grow: calc(var(--r));
  flex-basis: 0;
}

img {
  max-width: 100%;
}
```

```html
<ul>
  <li style="--r: 1920/1080">
    <img src="https://dummyimage.com/1920x1080"/>
  </li>
  <li  style="--r: 1400/1000">
    <img src="https://dummyimage.com/1400x1000"/>
  </li>
  <li  style="--r: 500/500">
    <img src="https://dummyimage.com/500"/>
  </li>
</ul>
```